# removing duplicates from html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the best way to remove the grapes duplicate from this? there are tons of ways of removing duplicates from simple arrays, but this would be an array with html elements

```
 <div class="fruit">
      grapes
 </div>
 <div class="fruit">
      bananas
 </div>
 <div class="fruit">
      grapes
  </div>
```

I've tried using something like

```
 $('.fruit').each(function () {
      $('.fruit:has("' + $(this).text() + '"):gt(0)').remove();  
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var obj = {};
$('.fruit').each(function(){
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    if(obj[text]){
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        obj[text] = true;
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FJAuK/)

Answer (score 2):

`:has` expects an element selector while `:contains` takes a string

see http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

so this should do the trick:

```
 $('.fruit').each(function () {
      $('.fruit:contains("' + $(this).text() + '"):gt(0)').remove();  
 });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kam7E/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/S3wXM/1/

Assuming that you wish to remove only one of the duplicates.

Using [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), like the answer above but implementation is slightly different.

```
$($("div:contains('grapes')")[0]).remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ - This also might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueFruits = [];
$(".fruit").each(function(i,e){
    var thisFruit = $.trim($(e).text());
    if(uniqueFruits.indexOf(thisFruit) == -1)
        uniqueFruits.push(thisFruit);
    else
        $(e).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7E9e/

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/UKRwf/

```
var found = {};
var $unique_fruits = $('.fruit').filter(function(){
   var data = this.innerHTML.trim();

   if(!found.hasOwnProperty(data)) return found[data] = true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working fiddle for this:-

http://jsfiddle.net/HwUUs/1/

```
$( "div:contains('grapes')" ).remove();
```

Comment: yes exactly, i also wanted to know that. I think the fiddle is perfectly fine, dont know why this has been done.