# remove div's with repeated class names

Tags: css

I have some classes

I want to remove duplicated class name.

Note: class names are created dynamically. I can't change `html` and only I can change css.

`first-of-type` not solved my problem.

```
<div class="download-1">some text</div>
<div class="download-12">some text</div>
<div class="download-14">some text</div>
<div class="download-14">some text</div> <--- i want remove this
<div class="download-12">some text</div>
```

Comment: Only class `download-14`? Even though you have another duplicate `download-12`?

Comment: Also you can't use css only. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096291/removing-duplicates-from-html-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a option to use jQuery, you can do this by following:

```js
var elem = {};
$('div').each(function() {
   var txt = $(this).attr('class');
   if (elem[txt])
       $(this).remove();
   else
       elem[txt] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="download-1">some text</div>
<div class="download-12">some text</div>
<div class="download-14">some text</div>
<div class="download-14">some text</div>
<div class="download-12">some text</div>
```